# How to get TagName of Control if exists?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, reflection, asp.net-controls

I have written this code:

```
    If (AlohaEnabled) Then
        Dim head As Control = Nothing
        For Each control In Master.Controls
            Dim field = control.GetType.GetField("TagName")
            If ((field IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (field.GetValue(control).Equals("head"))) Then
                'Add aloha scripts
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

If `AlohaEnabled` is `True`, then I intend to add some links and scripts to the `head` tag. I do not know in advance what kind of `Master` will be used, therefore I iterate its `Controls` and look for a field called `TagName` through reflection. If `field` has a value, then I compare it to `"head"` and if it is a match, then I intend to add aloha `script`s (the question is more general though, I could need this for different scripts as well or somewhere else). `TagName` is a field of [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). The 0'th `control` in my test case returns

```
{Name = "HtmlHead" FullName = "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead"}
```

on `control.GetType`. If we look at [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlhead(v=vs.110).aspx), we see that it inherits [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), which on its turn inherits [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), which inherits from `HtmlControl`. Since [TagName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.tagname(v=vs.110).aspx) is `Public`, I would expect `control.GetType.GetField("TagName")` to `Return` `"head"`. Instead of that, it returns `Nothing`. I wonder what is the cause of this behavior?

EDIT:

**FloatingKiwi** is right, the problem was that I was searching for a field, but this is a property, therefore I did not find it (what is the purpose of properties anyway, we can resolve their tasks with methods). I have used a work-around in the meantime:

```
        For Each control In Master.Controls
            If (TypeOf control Is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl) Then
                Dim htmlControl = CType(control, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl)
                If (htmlControl.TagName.Equals("head")) Then
                    'Add aloha scripts
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

I wonder which is the superior solution: my work-around, or property searching using reflection?

Comment: I have observed that the question was down-voted. If someone could explain the problem with the question, I could edit it to improve its quality or remove it if it is unsalvageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Property not a Field. Use

`Dim propInfo = control.GetType.GetProperty("TagName")` instead.

That will return a PropertyInfo object. To get the actual value use

`Dim result = propInfo .GetValue(control, Nothing)`

Comment: control.GetType.GetProperty("TagName").GetValue(control, Nothing) solves the problem indeed, but If (TypeOf control Is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl) Then Dim htmlControl = CType(control, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl) works well as well. I wonder which code is superior, the actual answer to my question or the work-around I implemented instead.

Comment: Please take a look at the question, which was edited. As you can see I have implemented a work-around and wonder whether it is better or worse than the solution you have shown (which is the answer to the question).

Comment: It's always better to go with the strongly typed approach rather than using reflection.

Comment: Thanks, mate, nice answer, nice comment :)